# Create a trigger after insert with a select in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a mysql trigger. The error code 1064 is very generic. The trigger is to see if a record exists for a particular key; and if it does update a particular column in the newly inserted row with that value. I am using a select query on the same table as the trigger is on. Does that cause a problem? Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER classid_insert
AFTER INSERT ON courses_semester
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET @class_id = (SELECT class_id FROM courses_semester WHERE 
 course_id = NEW.`course_id`
AND `dept_id` = NEW.`dept_id`
AND `univ_id` = NEW.`univ_id`
AND `section_id` = NEW.`section_id`
AND `semester` = NEW.`semester`
AND `year` = NEW.`year`);
IF(@class_id = NULL)
THEN
 NEW.class_id = UUID()
ELSE
 NEW.class_id = @class_id
END IF;
END

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: True, but doesn't even that generic error give you a line number on which the error occurs?

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't help either :)
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET @class_id = (SELECT class_id FROM courses_semester WHE' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your entire trigger code should look like below. remove the spaces after `DELIMITER $$` and before `DELIMITER ;`. Also, the last `END` need to changed to `END $$`. Also, it has to be an `BEFORE` trigger and not an `AFTER` trigger.

Moreover, `NEW.class_id = UUID()` is not correct.It's missing `SET` as

```
SET NEW.class_id = UUID();
```

CORRECTED TRIGGER CODE:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER classid_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON courses_semester
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET @class_id = (SELECT class_id FROM courses_semester WHERE 
 course_id = NEW.`course_id`
AND `dept_id` = NEW.`dept_id`
AND `univ_id` = NEW.`univ_id`
AND `section_id` = NEW.`section_id`
AND `semester` = NEW.`semester`
AND `year` = NEW.`year`);
IF(@class_id = NULL)
THEN
 SET NEW.class_id = UUID();
ELSE
 SET NEW.class_id = @class_id;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The `update` will always update **all** rows in the `course_semester` table each time a row is inserted. I don't think that is intended

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that's correct but if you see the post ... there is no condition also specified in trigger code. so I had to assume that part. Also, per post the main question was syntax error .. this is a extra pointer I added noticing that. At least will get him going !!!

Comment: Just as an update to the answer. You cannot use an update statement on the same table. So if somebody stumbles upon this the update should be replaced with SET NEW.class_id and the trigger should be fired 'Before' insert.

Comment: @user3648939, That a good point; not sure how I missed it completely. Thanks for pointing that. Updated my answer. Cool!